# CMFCMenuBar generated menu bar, how to use CMenu to dynamically add menu?

Tags: c++, mfc

This code does not get the effect I want, I want to dynamically add a custom menu on the CMFCMenuBar, it is independent

```cpp
CMenu   m_menuFromPlug;

int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    AddMenu();
}
    
void CMainFrame::AddMenu()
{
    m_menuFromPlug.CreatePopupMenu();
    CMenu *pMenu = CMenu::FromHandle(m_wndMenuBar.GetDefaultMenu());
    if (NULL != pMenu)
    {
        CString plugMStr = TEXT("Root Menu");
        while (m_menuFromPlug.GetMenuItemCount())
        {
            m_menuFromPlug.DeleteMenu(0, MF_BYPOSITION);
        }

        unsigned int flag = MF_ENABLED | MF_STRING;
        m_menuFromPlug.AppendMenu(flag, 500, TEXT("Item Menu"));

        MENUITEMINFOW menuStru;
        if (pMenu->InsertMenuItem(2, &menuStru, MF_BYPOSITION))
        {
            m_wndMenuBar.CreateFromMenu(pMenu->GetSafeHmenu(), TRUE, TRUE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are passing an uninitialized instance of `MENUITEMINFOW` to InsertMenuItem - what did you expect?  Also, the third parameter is a BOOL, not an MF flag.

Comment: [CMenu::InsertMenuItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmenu-class#insertmenuitem).

Comment: @IInspectable this may get overridden by `ON_WM_INITMENUPOPUP` response.